# Creating a "Delete all Results" button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what I have to do to provide a link to delete all of my "results"

I'm looking for something like:

```
<%= button_to 'Remove All', @results, delete_all %>
```

I'm using mysql.

**EDIT**
routes.rb:

```
Productfinder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :contacts
resources :helps
get "help/index"
resources :results
resources :extensions
resources :websites
resources :words
resources :results do
collection do
get 'remove_all'
end
end
get "home/index"
root :to => "results#index"
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all results from Result table?

Comment: @Ireneusz I wold like to delete all results in the table called results but not the table itself. Thanks

Comment: if so then Result.delete_all will work like a charm for you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful for you:

in routes.rb you should add:

```
#rails 3.0
resources :results do
  collection do
    get 'remove_all'
  end
end

#rails 2.3
map.resources :results, :collection => { :remove_all => :get }
```

in some view you can add this link:

```
<%= link_to "Remove All", remove_all_results_path, :method => :get %>
```

and controller's action (in app/controller/results_controller.rb):

```
def remove_all
  Result.delete_all
  flash[:notice] = "You have removed all results!"
  redirect_to results_path
end
```

Comment: Careful, `Result.delete_all` will truncate that database table. I don't think that's what he wants ;)

Comment: he want to delete all of his results, so I think he want to clear Result table :) But we shouldn't guess, we should ask him about it :)

Comment: Thankyou very muchly. However using this I get the error "Couldn't find Result with ID=remove_all" any suggestions?

Comment: strange... can you generate routes and see if remove_all_results_path is correct?

Comment: What rails version do you have?

Comment: sounds like you didnt route the remove_all path correctly. Make sure you chose the right code for that corresponds to your rails version.

Comment: if this is possible then please post your routes.rb, and check if you have only one 'resources :results' in this file, and it is not nested.

Comment: please remove completely "resources :results" from fifth line. Restart sever and check if this will help.

Comment: You should NEVER use a GET HTTP method that deletes something in a RESTful application. Use DELETE instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that it's a lot cleaner to just handle the delete all as individual destroy calls via javascript with checkboxes in your table. Here's what I do (using prototype.js):

```
function delete_selected () {
  var table_id;
  $$('table.data tr td.selector "]').each(function(e) {
    table_id = e.up('table').id;
    var id = e.up('tr').id;
    var destroy_link = e.up('tr').down('td#destroy a');

    var method = 'delete', url = destroy_link.readAttribute('href');

    var csrf_param = $$('meta[name=csrf-param]')[0], csrf_token = $$('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0];

    var params = {};
    params[csrf_param.readAttribute('content').toString()] = csrf_token.readAttribute('content');

    if (csrf_param) {
      new Ajax.Request(url, {    
        'method': method,
        'parameters': params,
        onSuccess: function (transport) {  
          highlight_row(e.up('tr'), 'deleted');
        },
        asynchronous: true
      });
    }
  });
```

Here is the necessary ruby code and a data table example (which is very similar to the default):

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>

<a href="#" onclick="delete_selected();">delete selected</a>

<table id="categories" class="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="selector"><input id="all" type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th id="id" class="value">Id</th>
      <th id="name" class="value">Name</th>
      <th id="show" class="action"></th>
      <th id="edit" class="action"></th>
      <th id="destroy" class="action"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <tr id="<%= category.id %>">
      <td class="selector"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td id="id" class="value"><%= category.id %></td>
      <td id="name" class="value"><%= category.name %></td>
      <td id="show" class="action"><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
      <td id="edit" class="action"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
      <td id="destroy" class="action"><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can ignore highlight_row. It's just a helper function to highlight and remove the deleted object from the table (without a page reload). I left it there so you can see how the callbacks can be managed.

Anyway, I know it's not a pure ruby fix, but as you can see, it would require very little effort to convert this from a delete_selected to a delete_all. Cheers.